# Java project with mysql database integration

Tags: java, sql, mysql

i am student who working on Railway management system in Java with mysql database integration,i almost finished my project, but there is one problem in the code that i'm sitting on for a couple of days and can't solve it, i also tried different resources chatGPT , github , and so on.

This is my question - I create an account in my system, and when I try to book a ticket, I get the error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rms`.`booking`, CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`))"

I want the information to be stored in the "booking" table when booking a ticket, so that it can then be displayed as bookingHistory.

below are the tables I use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_login VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
user_password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE admin (
admin_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
admin_login VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
admin_password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS journey (
    journey_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    source_station VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    destination_station VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    departure_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    arrival_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    available_seats INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking (
    booking_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    journey_id INT NOT NULL,
    booking_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (journey_id) REFERENCES journey(journey_id)
);
```

Below is the code I use:

```java
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


public class RailwayMS {
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RMS";
    private static final String USER = "ignat";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "gowent";
    private static boolean isAdmin = false;
    private static boolean isLoggedIn = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Ticket Booking System!");
                System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
                System.out.println("1. Login as Admin");
                System.out.println("2. Login as User");
                System.out.println("3. Register as User");
                System.out.println("4. Register as Admin");
                System.out.println("5. Exit");

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = 0;

                try {
                    choice = scanner.nextInt();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a valid option.");
                    scanner.nextLine(); // Очистка буфера сканера
                    continue; // Возврат к началу цикла
                }

                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        login(conn, true);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        login(conn, false);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        registerUser(conn);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        registerAdmin(conn);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private static void login(Connection conn, boolean isAdminLogin) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Please enter your username:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter your password:");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        String tableName = isAdminLogin ? "admin" : "user";
        String idColumnName = isAdminLogin ? "admin_id" : "user_id";
        String loginColumnName = isAdminLogin ? "admin_login" : "user_login";
        String passwordColumnName = isAdminLogin ? "admin_password" : "user_password";

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + loginColumnName + " = ? AND " + passwordColumnName + " = ?");
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            isLoggedIn = true;
            isAdmin = isAdminLogin;
            System.out.println("Login successful!");
            if (isAdmin) {
                showAdminMenu(conn);
            } else {
                showUserMenu(conn);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    private static void showUserMenu(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Ticket Booking System!");
            System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
            System.out.println("1. Book a ticket");
            System.out.println("2. View my booking history");
            System.out.println("3. View existing journeys");
            System.out.println("4. Logout");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    bookTicket(conn);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewBookingHistory(conn);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewJourneys(conn);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    logout();
                    return;
                case 5:
                    exitProgram();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void showAdminMenu(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Ticket Booking System!");
            System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
            System.out.println("1. Book a ticket");
            System.out.println("2. View my booking history");
            System.out.println("3. View booking history of a user using username");
            System.out.println("4. Add a new journey");
            System.out.println("5. View existing journeys");
            System.out.println("6. Logout");
            System.out.println("7. Exit");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    bookTicket(conn);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewBookingHistory(conn);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewUserBookingHistory(conn);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    addJourney(conn);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    viewJourneys(conn);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    logout();
                    return;
                case 7:
                    exitProgram();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }


    private static void registerAdmin(Connection conn) {
        boolean registrationSuccessful = false;
        while (!registrationSuccessful) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter an admin username:");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String username = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Please enter an admin password:");
                String password = scanner.nextLine();

                String tableName = "admin";
                String loginColumnName = "admin_login";
                String passwordColumnName = "admin_password";

                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + loginColumnName + ", " + passwordColumnName + ") VALUES (?, ?)");
                statement.setString(1, username);
                statement.setString(2, password);

                int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Admin registration successful!");
                    registrationSuccessful = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Admin registration failed. Please try again.");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                if (e.getErrorCode() == 1062) {
                    System.out.println("Admin username already exists. Please try a different username.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("An error occurred during admin registration. Please try again.");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static void registerUser(Connection conn) {
        boolean registrationSuccessful = false;
        while (!registrationSuccessful) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter a username:");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                String username = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
                String password = scanner.nextLine();

                String tableName = "user";
                String loginColumnName = "user_login";
                String passwordColumnName = "user_password";

                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + loginColumnName + ", " + passwordColumnName + ") VALUES (?, ?)");
                statement.setString(1, username);
                statement.setString(2, password);

                int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                    System.out.println("User registration successful!");
                    registrationSuccessful = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("User registration failed. Please try again.");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                if (e.getErrorCode() == 1062) {
                    System.out.println("Username already exists. Please try a different username.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("An error occurred during user registration. Please try again.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void bookTicket(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Please enter the journey ID:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int journeyId = scanner.nextInt();

        PreparedStatement journeyStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM journey WHERE journey_id = ?");
        journeyStatement.setInt(1, journeyId);
        ResultSet journeyResult = journeyStatement.executeQuery();

        if (journeyResult.next()) {
            int availableSeats = journeyResult.getInt("available_seats");
            if (availableSeats > 0) {
                System.out.println("Seats available. Booking ticket...");

                PreparedStatement updateStatement = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE journey SET available_seats = ? WHERE journey_id = ?");
                updateStatement.setInt(1, availableSeats - 1);
                updateStatement.setInt(2, journeyId);
                updateStatement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Ticket booked successfully!");



                try {
                    PreparedStatement insertStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO booking (user_id, journey_id, booking_time) VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
                    insertStatement.setInt(1, getUserId(conn));
                    insertStatement.setInt(2, journeyId);
                    insertStatement.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No seats available for this journey.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Journey not found.");
        }
    }



    private static void viewBookingHistory(Connection conn) throws SQLException {

        int userId = getUserId(conn);

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM booking INNER JOIN journey ON booking.journey_id = journey.journey_id WHERE user_id = ?");
        statement.setInt(1, userId);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            System.out.println("Booking History:");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            do {
                int bookingId = result.getInt("booking_id");
                String source = result.getString("source_station");
                String destination = result.getString("destination_station");
                String departureTime = result.getString("departure_time");
                String arrivalTime = result.getString("arrival_time");
                double price = result.getDouble("price");
                String bookingDate = result.getString("booking_time");


                System.out.println("Booking ID: " + bookingId);
                System.out.println("Journey: " + source + " to " + destination);
                System.out.println("Departure Time: " + departureTime);
                System.out.println("Arrival Time: " + arrivalTime);
                System.out.println("Price: " + price);
                System.out.println("Booking Date: " + bookingDate);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            } while (result.next());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No booking history found.");
        }
    }

    private static void viewUserBookingHistory(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        // Fetch the booking history for a specific user

        System.out.println("Enter the user ID:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userId = scanner.nextInt();

        // Fetch the booking history for the user
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM booking INNER JOIN journey ON booking.journey_id = journey.journey_id WHERE user_id = ?");
        statement.setInt(1, userId);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            System.out.println("Booking History for User ID " + userId + ":");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            do {
                int bookingId = result.getInt("booking_id");
                String source = result.getString("source_station");
                String destination = result.getString("destination_station");
                String departureTime = result.getString("departure_time");
                String arrivalTime = result.getString("arrival_time");
                double price = result.getDouble("price");
                String bookingDate = result.getString("booking_time");


                System.out.println("Booking ID: " + bookingId);
                System.out.println("Journey: " + source + " to " + destination);
                System.out.println("Departure Time: " + departureTime);
                System.out.println("Arrival Time: " + arrivalTime);
                System.out.println("Price: " + price);
                System.out.println("Booking Date: " + bookingDate);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            } while (result.next());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No booking history found for User ID " + userId + ".");
        }
    }


    private static void addJourney(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        if (isAdmin) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the journey details:");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Source Station: ");
            String source = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Destination Station: ");
            String destination = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Departure Time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS): ");
            String departureTime = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Arrival Time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS): ");
            String arrivalTime = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Price: ");
            double price = scanner.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Available Seats: ");
            int availableSeats = scanner.nextInt();

            // Insert the new journey into the database
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO journey (source_station, destination_station, departure_time, arrival_time, price, available_seats) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            statement.setString(1, source);
            statement.setString(2, destination);
            statement.setString(3, departureTime);
            statement.setString(4, arrivalTime);
            statement.setDouble(5, price);
            statement.setInt(6, availableSeats);

            int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                System.out.println("Journey added successfully!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to add journey. Please try again.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Only admins can add journeys.");
        }
    }



    private static void viewJourneys(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM journey");

        if (result.next()) {
            System.out.println("Existing Journeys:");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            do {
                int journeyId = result.getInt("journey_id");
                String source = result.getString("source_station");
                String destination = result.getString("destination_station");
                String departureTime = result.getString("departure_time");
                String arrivalTime = result.getString("arrival_time");
                double price = result.getDouble("price");

                System.out.println("Journey ID: " + journeyId);
                System.out.println("Source Station: " + source);
                System.out.println("Destination Station: " + destination);
                System.out.println("Departure Time: " + departureTime);
                System.out.println("Arrival Time: " + arrivalTime);
                System.out.println("Price: " + price);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            } while (result.next());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No existing journeys found.");
        }
    }

    private static int getUserId(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        String tableName = isAdmin ? "admin" : "user";
        String idColumnName = isAdmin ? "admin_id" : "user_id";
        String loginColumnName = isAdmin ? "admin_login" : "user_login";

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT " + idColumnName + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + loginColumnName + " = ?");
        statement.setString(1, getLoggedInUsername());

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            return result.getInt(idColumnName);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private static int getUserIdByUsername(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException {
        String tableName = "user";
        String idColumnName = "user_id";
        String loginColumnName = "user_login";

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT " + idColumnName + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + loginColumnName + " = ?");
        statement.setString(1, username);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            return result.getInt(idColumnName);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private static String getLoggedInUsername() {
        return isLoggedIn ? "loggedInUsername" : "";
    }

    private static void logout() {
        isLoggedIn = false;
        isAdmin = false;
        System.out.println("Logged out successfully!");
    }

    private static void exitProgram() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is the first time I ask such questions on such sites, and I will immediately say that I will be extremely grateful for any answer.

I read information about the error on different sites + searched for the solution code on github and asked chatGPT, but I did not receive the desired answer.
I just want to understand what the problem is and what needs to be changed in mysql or in java code in order to finally finish this project =)))

Comment: the column names as variable seems unnecessary

Comment: OK, first you have made a bad database design desision that would be better fixed now rather than later. Create a Users table and in that create a flag to indictae the user is an User or Admin. Dont use 2 seperate tables

Comment: You also appear to be using **Plain Text Passwords**. Thats a major __NoNo__ I am sure there is a hashing function in Java, please use it for the safety of your users, and your sanity

Comment: When posting here, strip down your code and your problem description to a *minimum* needed to show the issue.